# what regex to extract all data except within <> in perl?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have string

```
Message <Network=Data Center> All Verified
```

I need to extract all string except one in angular brackets

I tried

```
m/(?![^<]*\\>)/s
```

Not giving desired result.

Answer (score 3):

### Removing `<..>` regions

It's easier to remove the `<..>` parts from the string and then deal with the remaining string.

Try this oneliner:

```
cat file | perl -pne 's/<[^>]*?>//g;'
```

For your sample input, this is the output:

```
Message  All Verified
```

Notice the [non-greedy quantifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) `?` is used in the regex. Also, because this is a oneliner, the `s///` search-and-replace construct is applied to `$_` implicit variable (which is a line from standard input). So after search & replace has run in this oneliner, the `$_` will be altered(there will be no `<..>` regions in it). Also the `-p` was used in order to print the variable `$_` after running the block of code. You can read more about Perl commandline switches in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

This is one solution. Below there is another one:

### Capturing regions outside of `<..>`

On the other hand, you can(if you want) match the parts outside of the `<..>` regions.

In order to do that let's build a regex. First, we want a `<` or `>` free region. The following regex matches just that

`$p = ([^<>]*)`.

Next, we want to match everything before `<`, and for that we can write `(?:$p<)` and everything after `>`, and that's `(?:>$p)`.

Now if we assemble all those parts together we get `(?:>$p)|(?:$p<)`.

Notice that `(?:)` is a non-capturing group.

So now there are two capturing groups (the two `$p` you see above) but only one will match at a time, so some of the captures will be `undef`. We'll have to filter those out.

Finally, we can assemble all the captures, and we're done.

```
cat file | perl -ne '$p="([^<>]*)";@x=grep{defined} m{(?:>$p)|(?:$p<)}g; print join(" ",@x)."\n";'
```

### `Parse::Yapp` parser

You might think that using [`Parser::Yapp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse%3a%3aYapp) for this particular problem is a bit too much(usually, if you have something complicated to parse, you would use a grammar and a [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators)), but .. why not.. :)

Ok, so we need a grammar, here's one right here `grammar_file.yp`:

```
#header

%%

#rules
expression:
| exterior '<' interior '>' exterior
| exterior
;

exterior:
| TOK { $_[0]->YYData->{DATA} .= $_[1]; }
| expression
;

interior: TOK;

%%
#footer

sub Error { my ($parser)=shift; }

sub Lexer {
    use Data::Dumper;
    my($parser)=shift;
    $parser->YYData->{INPUT} or return('',undef);
    #$parser->YYData->{INPUT}=~s/^\s+//;
    for ($parser->YYData->{INPUT}) {
        return ('TOK',$1) if(s/^([^<>]+)//);
        return (   $1,$1) if(s/^([<>])//);
    };
}
```

You will notice in the grammar above that the `interior` is completely ignored, and only the terminals from `exterior` are collected.

Here's a small program that will use the parser(`MyParser.pm` generated from `grammar_file.yp`) `parse.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyParser;
my $parser=MyParser->new;
$parser->YYData->{INPUT} = "Message <Network=Data Center> All Verified";
my $value=$parser->YYParse(
    yylex   => \&MyParser::Lexer,
    yyerror => \&MyParser::Error,
    #yydebug => 0x1F,
);
my $nberr=$parser->YYNberr();
my $data=$parser->YYData->{DATA};
print "Result=$data"
```

And now a `Makefile` and we're done:

```
generate_parser_module:
    yapp -m MyParser grammar_file.yp; 

run:
    perl parse.pl

all: generate_parser_module
```

### Note

Some more Parser generators can be found here

- [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aGrammars)
- [Parse::RecDescent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse%3a%3aRecDescent)
- [Marpa::XS](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-XS) or [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa%3a%3aR2)

Comment: what is that semi colon at the end?

Comment: @Error_Coding The semi colon at the end is not required. One can do without that semi colon. I usually write oneliners with multiple statements so I have the habit of putting the semi colon in order to extend the oneliner if necessary.

Comment: Thanks !! but not working I am not able to capture the rest of string. if I give matching pattern within parenthesis it is not capturing
if($msg =~ m/(<[^>]*?>/)/i)something like this

Comment: I've expanded the answer with a matching approach too, instead of just the search&replace approach. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: added a parser generator, just in case you might want to try that approach :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it other way: just remove the string in the angular brackets:

```
s@<.*>@@
```

Or if `>` is not allowed:

```
s@<[^>]*>@@
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact approach. The following regex will capture your strings into Group 1:

```
<[^>]+>|([^<>]*)
```

What we are interested in here is not the overall match, but just the Group 1 matches.

So we need to iterate over Group 1 matches. I don't code in Perl, but following a recipe from the [perlretut tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl), this should do it:

```
 while ($x =~ /<[^>]+>|([^<>]*)/g) {
print "$1","\n";
}
```

Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
cat yourfile |sed 's/<.*>//g' > newfile
```

If you need `perl`:

```
 perl -i -pe "s/<.*?>//g" yourfile
```